# is_authenticated() raises TypeError TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I tried to use `is_authenticated()` in a view, but got the error `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

```
@auth.before_app_request
def before_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated() \
            and not current_user.confirmed \
            and request.endpoint[:5] != 'auth.' \
            and request.endpoint != 'static':
        return redirect(url_for('auth.unconfirmed'))
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

"object is not callable" error occurs when you are trying to behave an object like it is a method or function.

in this case:

```
current_user.is_authenticated()
```

you are behaveing current_user.is_authenticated as a method but its not a method .

you have to use it in this way :

```
current_user.is_authenticated
```

you use "( )" after methods or functions, not objects.

In some cases a class might implement `__call__` function which you can call an object too, then it will be callable.

Answer (score 13):

From [Flask-Login 0.3.0](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/CHANGES) (released on September 10th, 2015) changes:

> - BREAKING: The `is_authenticated`, `is_active`, and `is_anonymous` members of   the user class are now properties, not methods.
>     Applications should update   their user classes accordingly.

So you need to change your `user` class and code accordingly.