# django: code changes not getting reflected

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

I am using Django 2.0.

I wanted to use firebase cloud messaging, so i have installed **fcm_django**.

I have to replace `is_authenticated()` with `is_authenticated` (without the brackets) in the **`rest_framework.py`** file.

SO i have edited the file

```
/home/test/venv_btg/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fcm_django/api/rest_framework.py
```

Then i save the file.

But when i run the url. It shows the following error in the file rest_framework.py

```
 if user is not None and user.is_authenticated():
```

but i have changed `is_authenticated()` to `is_aunthenticated`

Why django is not reflecting the changes?

Comment: Can you update the detailed error log?

Comment: Basically can i directly edit files in site-packages folder, so that they reflect the respective changes

Comment: 'bool' object is not callable: https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django/issues/46. The solution i found is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983133/is-authenticated-raises-typeerror-typeerror-bool-object-is-not-callable and https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django/issues/43