# Django: python venv: Can i edit files in the lib/python3.6/site-packages

Tags: django, python-venv

I am using Django 2.0. and package fcm-django==0.2.13

After upgrading to `Django 2.0` I have found an error in lib/python3.6/site-packages/fcm_django/api/rest_framework.py it says

```
'bool' object is not callable at the below line

 if user is not None and user.is_authenticated():
```

I have found the solution at https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django/issues/43 and also [is_authenticated() raises TypeError TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983133/is-authenticated-raises-typeerror-typeerror-bool-object-is-not-callable)

I have to replace is_authenticated() with is_authenticated (without the brackets) in the `lib/python3.6/site-packages/fcm_django/api/rest_framework.py` file. The latest package fcm-django==0.2.13 is not yet updated with this error.

SO i have edited the file

/home/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fcm_django/api/rest_framework.py
Then i save the file.

But when i run the url. It shows the same error in the file rest_framework.py

if user is not None and user.is_authenticated():

but i have changed is_authenticated() to is_aunthenticated

Why django/venv is not reflecting the changes?

Comment: Please don`t edit third party packages installed as library. Did you upgrade rest_framework ?

Comment: Looks like it is fcm_django that needs to be upgraded; there is a [pull request](https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django/pulls) on that repo but it hasn't been merged. You could maybe install [that fork](https://github.com/jmitchel3/fcm-django/).

Comment: After editing the file in `site-packages`, there may still be cached pyc files in `__pycache__`. It would be better to install the fork as Daniel suggests.

Comment: yes thats the problem. I am stuck up. How to install the fork

Comment: You can install source packages from a git link: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-vcs

Comment: https://github.com/jmitchel3/fcm-django/blob/master/fcm_django/api/rest_framework.py. they havent changed  is_authenticated() to is_aunthenticated yet

Comment: I have downloaded the zip file of source. And then changed is_authenticated() to is_authenticated and then pip install localfile. But the error remains same

Comment: I have first uninstalled using `pip uninstall fcm_django` and then installed the modified package `pip install fcm_django.zip`  then the error is gone. thank you very much  struggling since 1 day